# java.text.Collator treats "v" and "w" as the same letter for Swedish language/locale

Tags: java, java-8

The following test passes correctly with Java 8.

```
Comparator<String> stringComparator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("sv", "SE"));

Assert.assertTrue(stringComparator.compare("aaaa", "bbbb") < 0);
Assert.assertTrue(stringComparator.compare("waaa", "vbbb") < 0);
Assert.assertTrue(stringComparator.compare("vaaa", "wbbb") < 0);
```

This orders `waaa` before `vbbb` and `vaaa` before `wbbb`. Apparently it treats `v` and `w` as the same letter.

In fact, according to Wikipedia, in Swedish language:

> By 2006, 'W' had grown in usage because of new loanwords, so 'W' officially became a letter, and the 'V' = 'W' sorting rule was deprecated. Pre-2006 books and software generally use the rule. After the rule was deprecated, some books and software continued to apply it.

Does anyone have a general workaround to this, so that `v` and `w` are treated as separate letters within Swedish locale?

Comment: Weird! I can confirm that this is still the case in the Java 10 libraries.

Comment: Can https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html help?

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the standard `java.text.Collator`? As that type has a `getInstance` method rather than `newInstance` and implements `Comparator<Object>` rather than `Comparator<String>`…

Comment: I don’t see that cited statement on Wikipedia (https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svenska_alfabetet). All I can see, is that a specific dictionary used a differentiation between `W` and `V` for its glossary while the same authors still recommend using the old rules for Swedish names. Neither order is wrong. Besides that, you should never assert that the result of a comparator is precisely `+1` or `-1`, all that matters is the *sign* of the result.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your remarks, it is ``getInstance``, indeed. I will also edit the tests.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

Check the value of the string returned by

```
((RuleBasedCollator)Collator.getInstance(new Locale("sv", "SE"))).getRules()
```

and modify it to suit your needs and then create a new collator with your modified rules.

And probably submit a JDK bug report too, for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

> This orders waaa before vbbb and vaaa before wbbb. Apparently it
>   treats v and w as the same letter.

JDK indeed doesn't treat 'w' and 'v' as the same characters even in Swedish locale. The letter 'v' comes before 'w'.

`Assert.assertEquals(1, stringComparator.compare("w", "v"));//TRUE`

However, based on the Swedish collation rules, JDK orders 'wa' ahead of 'vb'.

`Assert.assertEquals(1, stringComparator.compare("wa", "vb"));//FALSE`

Comment: Since this doesn't solve the problem, it would be more suitable as a comment on the question.

Comment: @Lii, it does kind of solve OP's problem by demonstrating with a code sample that it is not a bug in JDK which differentiates between v and w for Swedish locale.

Comment: It treats them as different characters, but only of a secondary difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom comparator, which wraps the collator and manually handles `v` and `w` the way you want.

I have made two implementations of this.

The first one is short and elegant, it uses Guavas [`lexicographical`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#lexicographical-java.util.Comparator-) comparator together with the tricky regex that Holger provided in a comment.

```
private static final Pattern VW_BOUNDARY = Pattern.compile("(?=[vw])|(?<=[vw])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static Comparator<String> smallCorrectVwWrapper(Comparator<Object> original) {
    return Comparator.comparing(
        s -> Arrays.asList(VW_BOUNDARY.split((String) s)),
        Comparators.lexicographical(original));
```

The second implementation is a big and complex thing that does the same thing, but manually implemented, without libraries and regexes.

```
public static Comparator<String> correctVwWrapper(Comparator<Object> original) {
    return (s1, s2) -> compareSplittedVw(original, s1, s2);
}

/**
 * Compares the two string by first splitting them into segments separated by W
 * and V, then comparing the segments one by one.
 */
private static int compareSplittedVw(Comparator<Object> original, String s1, String s2) {
    List<String> l1 = splitVw(s1);
    List<String> l2 = splitVw(s2);

    int minSize = Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size());

    for (int ix = 0; ix < minSize; ix++) {
        int comp = original.compare(l1.get(ix), l2.get(ix));
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp; 
        }
    }

    return Integer.compare(l1.size(), l2.size());
}

private static boolean isVw(int ch) {
    return ch == 'V' || ch == 'v' || ch == 'W' || ch == 'w';
}


/**
 * Splits the string into segments separated by V and W.
 */
public static List<String> splitVw(String s) {
    var b = new StringBuilder();

    var result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int offset = 0; offset < s.length();) {
        int ch = s.codePointAt(offset);

        if (isVw(ch)) {
            if (b.length() > 0) {
                result.add(b.toString());
                b.setLength(0);
            }

            result.add(Character.toString((char) ch));
        } else {
            b.appendCodePoint(ch);
        }

        offset += Character.charCount(ch);
    }

    if (b.length() > 0) {
        result.add(b.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Comparator<String> stringComparator = correctVwWrapper(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("sv", "SE")));

    System.out.println(stringComparator.compare("a", "z") < 0);     // true
    System.out.println(stringComparator.compare("wa", "vz") < 0);   // false
    System.out.println(stringComparator.compare("wwa", "vvz") < 0); // false
    System.out.println(stringComparator.compare("va", "wz") < 0);   // true
    System.out.println(stringComparator.compare("v", "w") < 0);     // true
}
```

---

It is a little more work to implement a wrapping `Collator`, but it should not be too complicated.

Comment: That’s fine for this handful of test strings, but what if `v` or `w` appear at a different location than the first?

Comment: @Holger: Oh. You're right. I don't know from where I got the idea that only the first char matters. I'll try to come up with a solution, otherwise I'll remove the answer.

Comment: @Holger: I added a second attempt at implementing the correction logic. The complexity of this makes me think that 
DodgyCodeException's solution maybe is pretty good, even it you have to learn about weird collation rule syntax...

Comment: Yeah, that’s really complex. Note that you could just split by calling `split("(?=[vVwV])|(?<=[vVwW])")` on `s1` and `s2`. Or, if you want to optimize it, prepare the operation via `static final Pattern VW_BOUNDARY = Pattern.compile("(?=[vw])|(?<=[vw])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` and use it in the comparison method via `VW_BOUNDARY.split(s1)` and `VW_BOUNDARY.split(s2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently had this issue and thought I would share my half-assed solution. This is based on what @DodgyCodeExceptions wrote but I include the code I used.

```
 MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator();
    Locale locale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
    collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
    String collRuleSVStr = ((RuleBasedCollator) collator).getRules();
// For some reason removing this part of the string get us what we want.
    String newCollRulesSVStr = collRuleSVStr.replace("Ø & V ; w , W& Y,", "");
    RuleBasedCollator newColl = new RuleBasedCollator(newCollRulesSVStr );
    comparator.setCollator(newColl);
```

I used the getRules() method to get the rules string and printed it out.
This isn't the whole string but just the parts containing the rules for letters:

```
<a,A<b,B<c,C<d,D<ð,Ð<e,E<f,F<g,G<h,H<i,I<j,J<k,K<l,L<m,M<n,N<o,O<p,P<q,Q<r,R<s, S & SS,ß<t,T& TH, Þ &TH, þ <u,U<v,V<w,W<x,X<y,Y<z,Z&AE,Æ&AE,æ&OE,Œ&OE,œ& Z < å , Å< ä , Ä < a̋, A̋ < æ , Æ < ö , Ö < ő , Ő ; ø , Ø & V ; w , W& Y, ü , Ü; ű, Ű
```

The parts relevant to V and W are:

```
U<v,V<w,W<x,
```

and

```
Ø & V ; w , W& Y,
```

The first part looks ok and is the same for other languages such as Norwegian.
So I figured the second part had to be causing a problem so I simply removed it from the string and created a new collation. I am not proficient enough in the syntax to tell you exactly why this part is causing Wa to come before Vb, but simply creating custom Collate without that part works.

Perhaps someone without some insight can explain.